# Find the volume of the pyramid

Tags: calculus, geometry

The base of the pyramid is an isosceles triangle with the base angle $\alpha$.Each of the base dihedral angles is equal to $\phi$.The radius of the sphere inscribed in the pyramid is R.Find the volume of the pyramid.At what value of $\alpha$ is the volume of the pyramid the least?

I know that volume of pyramid is $\frac{1}{3}$area of base .height.Further I don’t know how to attempt.

Comment: Yes it is a typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Using sine law the area of the isosceless triangle (call the 2 equal sides $a$) is $A=a^2.\sin(\pi-2\alpha)=a^2.\sin(2\alpha)$